# Vulkan hpp wrappers, signature conflict

Tags: c++, header, wrapper, vulkan

I am trying to convert my existing codebase to use the wrappers define in vulkan.hpp in the lunar SDK.

In particular, I had the line of code:

`vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);`

Which is the native C like way to do stuff with vulkan.

I tried changing it to:

`vk::enumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);`
Which is the naming convention for vulkan.hpp. This however fails to compile, with multiple errors, the first being `error: ‘unsigned int*’ is not a class, struct, or union type`

The signature defined in vulkan.hpp is:

```
template <typename Allocator, typename Dispatch>
  VULKAN_HPP_INLINE typename ResultValueType<std::vector<LayerProperties,Allocator>>::type enumerateInstanceLayerProperties(Allocator const& vectorAllocator, Dispatch const &d )
```

My assumption was then that the first argument needs to be a vector:
`std::vector<vk::LayerProperties> availableLayers;
    vk::enumerateInstanceLayerProperties(availableLayers, nullptr);`

However that also fails to compile, warning me about:
 `error: request for member ‘vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties’ in ‘d’, whichis of non-class type ‘std::nullptr_t’`

`d` being the second parameter to the function.

What does the dispatch need to be to successfully compile this piece of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the C++ headers, that functions does not take any arguments at all and instead just returns a vector of `vk::LayerProperties` directly, so you simply assign the result:

```
std::vector<vk::LayerProperties> instanceLayerProps = vk::enumerateInstanceLayerProperties();
```

Which also saves you having to call the function twice, like with the C headers, where you first need to get the count do allocate your vector. This is all done implicitly here.